# Internet Explorer not changing span contents even though input is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

just a small questions cause I'm running in circles.

https://jsfiddle.net/sLxvcezv/2/

Basically in Internet Explorer it wont update my span contents even tho my input is valid. For other browsers the span contents will change.

So thats it I hope somebody takes a look at the fiddle and can help me.
Thanks

HTML

```
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" id="formId1" name="validateForm1">
  <table class="inputTables" id="create_trck_table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Attribute</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><input id="id1" maxlength="9" title="e.g AMS30-E3" type="text" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

<p id="myP">
</p>
```

CSS

```
input[type="text"]:invalid+span::after {
  color: red;
  content: "X";
}

input[type="text"]:valid+span::after {
  content: "\2713";
  color: limegreen;
}
```

Javascript (Jquery)

```
$(':input').on('keydown', function() {
  var valid = $('#id1').is(':valid');
  $('#myP').html('The Input is ' + valid);
})
```

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/sLxvcezv/2/ (IE is blocking the http: script because you're loading a https: URL)

Comment: @ChrisG this doesn't seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding this to the CSS

```
    input[value=""] + span::after 
    {
    content: "";
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qnt5zew8/